# Inner Join Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

```
CrystalReportAct crt = new CrystalReportAct();
sqlcon.Open();

sql = "SELECT EmpLog.Date, JobCategory.JobDesc, 
        Client.CompDesc, Product.ProdName, EmpLog.Actions, EmpLog.Remarks 
        FROM Client 
        INNER JOIN EmpLog ON Client.CompCode = EmpLog.CompCode 
        INNER JOIN JobCategory ON EmpLog.JobCode = JobCategory.JobCode 
        INNER JOIN Product ON EmpLog.ProdCode = Product.ProdCode 
        WHERE (EmpLog.EmpID = '"+empID+"')";

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlcon);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds, "Client");
adp.Fill(ds, "Emplog");
adp.Fill(ds, "JobCategory");
adp.Fill(ds, "Product");

crt.SetDataSource(ds);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crt;
```

This runs but has the wrong output. The output is almost 80 rows instead of just 3 rows.

Comment: The output will depend on the number of rows in each table. This fields you are using for join, are they all PK's?

Comment: yes all primary key. What do i need to do to make it the output for the Emplog table only where JobCategory,Product and Client are only foreign.

Comment: But my query is correct, and the output in MSSQL is rigth. But the thing here is in the code? I doubt. Help me here Mr.@AndersonSilva

Comment: On a side note, please use `SQLParameters` instead of concatenating the SQL string yourself. Whilst if it's just an int it's not vulnerable to SQL injection, it's still better for performance that way.

Comment: @Bridge - noted on that.

Comment: How about changing the query to SELECT ... FROM EmpLog INNER JOIN Client ON Client.CompCode = EmpLog.CompCode ... all the tables looks like having a relation with the EmpLog table.

Comment: Mr @ray - it's not working too. Somebody can advice what to do here?

Comment: 1) Is it showing 80 different rows or are there repeated values? 2) You say it's supposed to return only 3 rows. So, I assuming you've run this query against your SQL server manually for that specific employee ID and it returned 3 rows? 3) How did you set up the Data Source in your actual report template?

Comment: Furthermore, what is the significance of `CompCode` -- how many records can exist in `Client` for that code and how many records can exist in `EmpLog` for that code? You said they're all primary keys, but I'm having trouble understanding how there is only one EmpLog per `CompCode` if you're using `EmpID` to limit the list.

Comment: Finally @ray I think you've spotted the possible culprit and it should be `SELECT ... FROM EmpLog INNER JOIN Client ON EmpLog.CompCode = Client.CompCode` but this is assuming each Employee can only have one possible CompCode.

Answer (score 0):

In crt.SetDataSource(ds) statement specify the table name also otherwise it take the total rows.